# SQL Match Strings

Tags: java, sql, string, translation

I'm running into a problem regarding matching of strings.
What I want is to match a name in a table with another name that contains the same name + a port name following.

```
eg.
TABLE:
       name
1      abc
2      abc.8002
3      bcd
4      qwe
5      qwe.8002

Where the result would be another table of the form:

TABLE:
    name
1   abc
2   abc.8002
3   qwe
4   qwe.8002
```

I've described the problem in java code, and if you could help me with a translation, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
List temp = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String name1 : Names) {
    for (String name2 : Names) {
        if (name1 != name2
        && name2.contains(name1.substring(0,2))) {
             temp.add(name1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SELECT name FROM TABLE WHERE name like 'abc%' ` - Are you looking for this?

Comment: No, the names can vary a lot. And that would only get me abc.8002

Comment: So full name shouldnt be the same only the 3 character prefix?

Comment: yeah the names will always be the same first 3 characters and then followed by a port. I want to chose the ones that has a port.

Comment: `like 'abc%'` returns both `abc` and `abc.8002`.

Comment: yes! I want all the duplicates though they are not exact duplicates. Where the substring of the first 3 characters is a duplicate.

Comment: @Fildor, He is looking for partially duplicates.

Comment: @jarlh Yes, but I misunderstood OP's intentions. I think the SQL example is misleading.

Comment: @Fildor, we are all guessing here...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Do a self join. Use `LIKE` to match the names.

```
select t1.name
from tablename t1
join tablename t2
    on  (t1.name like t2.name || '%' or t2.name like t1.name || '%')
    and  t1.name <> t2.name
```

`||` is ANSI SQL concatenation. Some products have `concat()` or `+` instead.

To "select the ones that are partially duplicates on the first 3 letters" you can use `SUBSTRING()` instead of `LIKE`:

```
select t1.name
from tablename t1
join tablename t2
    on  substring(t1.name from 1 for 3) = substring(t2.name from 1 for 3)
    and t1.name <> t2.name
```

ANSI SQL syntax here too. Some dbms have `SUBSTR(t1.name, 1, 3)` or `LEFT(t1.name, 3)` or similar.

Comment: This is close to what i want, though there is only 1 table. The table has all the names and i want to select the ones that are partially duplicates on the first 3 letters.

Comment: @KasperLederballeSørensen Yes: **self** join. t1 and t2 are the same table.

Comment: With the second approach i still get the ones that do not have a partial duplicate because the two tables are the same.

Comment: @KasperLederballeSørensen, of course... Now corrected!!! (Require different names, same beginning. Would be even better to have different id or similar.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.
Play round with the JOINs, thogh.

```
SELECT T.NAME
FROM TABLE T
    INNER JOIN (SELECT NAME
    FROM (
        SELECT SUBSTRING(NAME,1,3) AS NAME FROM TABLE
    )
    GROUP BY NAME
    HAVING COUNT(NAME) > 1) C
WHERE T.NAME like C.NAME || '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tidied up a bit :

```
select t1.name
from TABLENAME t
inner join TABLENAME t1 on (substring(t1.name,1,3) = t.name and t1.name regexp '[a-z]{3}\.[0-9]{4}')
                       or (substring(t.name,1,3) = t1.name and t.name regexp '[a-z]{3}\.[0-9]{4}')
```